# Unable to remove HTML tags from string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting a property called "JobDescription" in response from an API which contains HTML tags inside. I am trying to remove html tags from inside the string but its not working.

**Code:**

```
 var jobDescription= "<P> kajskjdhkj</p> <div> lakjsklj/div>";
 console.log($sce.trustAsHtml(jobDescription)); // output : {}
```

**Expected Output :**

```
kajskjdhkj lakjsklj
```

I know we use it with "ng-bind-html" directive. Is it not possible to use it in the script to remove "html tags"?

My last option would be to use "regex" or any other logic to remove the HTML tags from the string but my first option would be to stick to standard way of using `$sce.trustAsHtml` function.

Comment: That output looks like an empty object. What does `response` look like?

Comment: @charlietfl Updated to question to show sampledata in "jobDescription" variable. Actually, I am trying to generate a JsonLD script tag on scripting front that's why I want to remove HTML tags from the string

Comment: It may work if it were an object instead of a string?

Comment: $sce.trustAsHtml will not give you a string without tags. It will allow you to display the HTML on the page, as in ng-bind-html="jobDescription"

Comment: What is expected result? Can use `angular.element` to get the text if that's all you want

Comment: @charlietfl Updated question with expected output. I just want to remove HTML tags from the string. Can you post your answer with how I can use angular.element to remove HTML tags from string please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach using `angular.element(html).text()`

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('main', function() {
    var jobDescription = "<P> kajskjdhkj</p> <div> lakjsklj</div>";    
    this.txt = angular.element(jobDescription).text()
    
    var sample ="Abc. Xyz Lmn No.1234 H, PPP TTT GGG, LKH 3</br>" 
    this.txt2 = angular.element('<div>').html(sample).text()
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main as $ctrl">
  {{$ctrl.txt}}<br/><br/>
  {{$ctrl.txt2}}
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me. angular.element removes HTML tags from the string? Can you explain what is happening here

Comment: `angular.element` is a lite version of jQuery like methods https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: I am getting error with this input "Abc. Xyz Lmn No.1234 H, PPP TTT GGG, LKH 3</br>"

Comment: OK... added another example that creates a temporary element to insert into, then extract text

Answer (score 1):

I use a filter for this sort of thing:

```
app.filter('stripTags', function() {
        return function(text) {
            return text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
        };
    })
```

Then in your controller:

```
var jobDescription= "<P> kajskjdhkj</p> <div> lakjsklj</div>";
var jobDescription_notags = $filter("stripTags")(jobDescription)
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me :)